# Current flow in PMOS when not active

Tags: current, cmos, nmos, pmos, nand

how can it be that Q2 is active when VA and VB are HIGH? 
If I understand correctly, a current (shown in yellow) should flow... 
But that is in my understanding not possible because both NMOS are disabled! And if there would be a current at the base of Q1, Q1 and Q2 are both active and hence a short circuit would happen.

So why is Q2 enabled?

[image]

Comment: Ugh.  Those discrete power MOSFET symbols should not be used for IC schematics.  Plus the PMOS ones are upside down.  Horribly confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an NMOS receives a logic "1", it'll start conducting and sink current, thus its drain will go to 0V. A PMOS will be turned off because its VGS voltage (provided that its source is connected to VDD) will be 0V; it is switched off.

However, in this situation, the current flowing through the NMOSes will create a drop the base of Q2 due to the resistor, thus source of the bottom-most NMOS is not at 0V. This will turn on Q2 and drive Vo down to VCEsat (it cannot go lower than the collect-emitter saturation voltage of Q2).

Your lecture notes appear to be right.